# Artin exercise 2.20

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Could someone take a look at my solution to this exercise in Artin?

> Let $a,b$ be elements of an abelian group of orders $m$ and $n$ respectively. What can you say about the order of their product, $ab$?

**Solution.** First, we consider a lemma that $(ab)^m = a^m b^m$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ for $a, b$ in some abelian group $G$. The base case holds since 
$$(ab)^1 = a^1 b^1 = ab.$$
Assuming the result for $n = k$: 
$$(ab)^k = a^k b^k.$$
Proving the result for $n = k + 1$: 
$$\begin{align}
(ab)^{k+1} & = (ab)^k (ab) \\
&= a^k b^k (ab)\\
& = (a^k a)(b^k b)\\
& = a^{k+1} b^{k+1},
\end{align}$$
wherein the final step relies on associativity and commutativity in $G$. Hence, the result is proved for all natural numbers $n$.

By the definition of the order of elements, we have $a^m = e$ and $b^n = e$. Hence, $|ab| \leq mn$, as
$$\begin{align}
(ab)^{mn} &= a^{mn} b^{mn}\\
& = (a^m)^n (b^n)^m\\
& = e^n e^m\\
& = ee \\
&= e.
\end{align}$$
Of course, for any integer multiple $k(mn)$ of $mn$, we also have $(ab)^{mn} = e$: 
$$\begin{align}
(ab)^{kmn}& = a^{kmn} b^{kmn} \\
&= (a^m)^{kn} (b^n)^{km}\\
& = e^{kn} e^{km} \\
&= ee \\
&= e.
\end{align}$$
However, there exist cases in which $|ab| < mn$. Take $a = (12)$ and $b = (1234)$ in the group $S_4$ under composition of permutations. We have $|a| = 2$, $|b| = 4$, but $|ab| = \text{lcm}(2,4) = 4 < 8$.

Hence, $|ab| \leq mn$.

Further, let $\ell = \text{lcm}(m,n)$. Hence, there exist positive integers $s$ and $t$ such that $\ell = sm = tn$. We have: 
$$\begin{align}
(ab)^{\ell} &= a^{\ell} b^{\ell} \\
& = a^{sm} b^{tn}\\
& = (a^m)^s (b^n)^t\\
& = e^s e^t \\
&= ee\\
& = e.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Actually, your idea of considering the lcm is very good. After considering $a^{lcm(m,n)}$ and $b^{lcm(m,n)}$, you can calculate $(ab)^{lcm(m,n)}$. Your example inside $S_4$ is a bit problematic, as you consider a non-abelian group there...

Comment: I edited my answer with a proof that, for lcm$(m,n) = \ell$, we have $(ab)^{\ell} = e$. So it is certainly the case that $|ab| \leq \ell \leq mn$. I cannot seem to figure out, though, if it is possible for $|ab| < \ell$. If that's the case, I should be able to conclude that $|ab| = \ell$.

Comment: Note that for any element $x$ in a group $G$, if $x^k = e$, then the order of $x$ is not only smaller than $k$ but actually divides it. Your proof of $(ab)^\ell = e$ looks good (missing one "$=$", though). However, you will not be able to show $|ab| = \ell$, for example if $a = b^{-1}$, then $a$ and $b$ have the same order but $ab = e$ has order $1$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, one final question. Your statement that if $x^k = e$, then $|x| \mid k$ makes perfect sense. I am trying to think of a way to prove this fact, though, instead of appealing to intuition. Any hints on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to show the more general statement that if you have $x^r = e = x^s$ then you also have $x^{gcd(r,s)} = e$ (by writing $gcd(r,s) = u r + v t$ for some $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$).